# How to sync large directory (30gb) between Android and OSX devices?

Tags: macos, sync, android, dropbox, data-transfer

So, my laptop is a Mac, and my phone is an Android. I want to sync my music directory between the two. The sync can either be multi-directional, or in a single direction from computer to phone.

I found an app called [Folder Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.SyncFolders&hl=en), which seems to work well, but not at directories of this size. The app keeps the entire directory in working memory on the computer, which obviously isn't an option for something this big.

What are the options? Surely there must be a decent solution out there for Android? Or is my best option to upgrade my Dropbox account...?

Comment: If you're not opposed to a cloud based solution, have you looked into Google Play Music? You can keep up to 50,000 songs in Google Play music for free. There was also an app I looked into long ago called [doubleTwist](https://www.doubletwist.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a solution called Bittorrent Sync in the past to do large folder syncing between multiple Android devices and computers, and now they have an iOS app.

The use an encrypted tunnel and Bittorrent technology to efficiently synchronize between multiple devices.

I've used this for music files and entire multi-gigabyte harddrives and it generally worked well and quickly.

Comment: Can you explain how you set this up?

Comment: It's simple but it's been a year since I used it personally. Generally you install the app or program on all the computers/phones you need to sync between, and set up a sync partnership. What I do know is that it does what you need and works well in my experience. Also apparently it had gone through a rebranding and is now called "Resilio" in order to better appeal to enterprise.